# ThreadLocal variable is always null

Tags: java, thread-safety

I have a Spring application which creates my business logic method as a bean.

My code looks like:

```
public class MyClass {
    private ThreadLocal<String> object1 = new ThreadLocal<String>();

    public String myMethodFoo(MyTestObject testobject) { 

        object1.set("Blah");
        ...
        ...
        ...

        return object1.get();
    }

}
```

Now when I run my unit test which calls this method, I always get a null pointer exception on the line where I set the variable value i.e `object1.set("Blah")`.

But somehow it magically disappears when I declare the ThreadLocal object as final. Do ThreadLocal objects always have to be declared final?

Comment: Please provide a [mcve].

Comment: Does your test actually run multiple threads? If so, you're assigning to object1 in one thread and reading from it from multiple; that's a data race. You need to make sure the reads have a formal happens-before relationship to the write, and I've easy to do that is by making the variable final.

Comment: Well no, I am testing it only using single thread for now to understand how it works. I was confused when it showed me null values only with a single threaded application itself.

Answer (score 3):

No, a `ThreadLocal` does not have to be defined as `final` (same rules as with other variables apply here) and it is possible that some other thread is changing your `object1` variable to `null`.

However, [`ThreadLocal` variables should be declared `static`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/ThreadLocal.html) because:

> This class provides thread-local variables. These variables differ
>   from their normal counterparts in that each thread that accesses one
>   (via its get or set method) has its own, independently initialized
>   copy of the variable. **`ThreadLocal` instances are typically private
>   static fields in classes that wish to associate state with a thread
>   (e.g., a user ID or Transaction ID).**